# ImageSpan Size Measurement with TextView and StaticLayout

Tags: android, textview, imagespan, staticlayout

I have a simple layout contains just one `TextView`.

I wanna load an image into `TextView` using ImageSpan.

Below method creates `Spannable`:

```
private Spannable getImageSpannable(int drawableId, int targetWidth, int targetHeight) {

    Bitmap originalBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), drawableId);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(originalBitmap, targetWidth, targetHeight, true);
    Drawable dr = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(), bitmap);
    dr.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());

    Spannable imageSpannable = new SpannableString("\uFFFC");
    ImageSpan imgSpan = new ImageSpan(dr, DynamicDrawableSpan.ALIGN_BOTTOM);

    imageSpannable.setSpan(imgSpan, 0, 1, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
    return imageSpannable;
}
```

I use this method to create content like this:

```
public void setContent() {

    SpannableStringBuilder content = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    content.append(getImageSpannable(R.drawable.my_image, 100, 260));
    content.append("\n");

    txtContent.setText(content);
}
```

When I call `setContent()` method my result is something like this:

[image: Small gap above ImageSpan]

As you see there is small gap between ImageSpan and top of `TextView`.

This is not line spacing, because I set line spacing to 0.

And interesting point is when I remove "\n" from content(declared in setContent method) this space is gone.

And another point is that when I tried to measure content size using `StaticLayout`, with "\n" at the end bottom of line 0 it returns 270 and without "\n" it returns 260.

This behavior causes some difficulties for me, because I have to measure text and ImageSpan using `StaticLayout` and decide witch one can fit into `TextView`.

I appreciate everyone can help me.

Thanks.

Here's my xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtContent"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="500dp"
    android:background="#fed9f4"
    android:textSize="22sp"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'v done some tests and I find that font size is affects ImageSpan rendering.

Can somebody explain this affect please?

Comment: post your xml too

Answer (score -1):

I hope this method works

The following line of code

```
public void setContent() {

    SpannableStringBuilder content = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    content.append(getImageSpannable(R.drawable.my_image, 100, 260));
    content.append("\n");

    txtContent.setText(content);
}
```

Change to

```
public void setContent() {

    SpannableStringBuilder content = new SpannableStringBuilder();
    content.append(getImageSpannable(R.drawable.my_image, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    content.append("\n");

    txtContent.setText(content);
}
```

And resize "R.drawable.my_image" dimensions

Comment: I don't want to resize image to WRAP_CONTENT. I have to resize it to specific size